# Killing field associate to an element in the Lie Algebra

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, principal-bundles

Given a principal $G$ bundle $E\to M$, where $G$ is a Lie group, I was told that for every $u \in \mathfrak{g}$ (the Lie algebra of $G$) we can define a $G$-invariant vector field $X_u$ over $E$. I'm trying to figure out how this field is defined:

since we have canonical identifications of $\mathfrak{g}\cong T_gG$ for every $g$, it makes sense to expect that the vector field will associate to each point in a fiber, the vector represented by $u$ (seen as a vector in $T_gG$). The problem is that this association seems to depend on how I identify the fibre with $G$ and I'm not able to prove that it's independent from it (hence well-defined).

Assuming it's well-defined, it's clearly left-invariant (I hope it's what it's meant by $G$-invariant).

How can I show that's well-defined?

**EDIT**: the statement above comes from "John Roe's Elliptict Operators, Topology and asymptotic methods" page 23, at the bottom

Comment: It seems that Tsemo's answer is indeed what you were told about. Do note, though, that this intrinsically defined vector field is *not* $G$-invariant.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval what do you mean by $G$-invariant? I'm saying that because I can't find the definition (the only one who keeps on pooping out in the context of lie algebras is left-invariant)

Comment: As Tsemo wrote in his answer, $G$ acts on $E$. Let us think of an element $g\in G$ as a diffeomorphism from $E$ to itself. We say that a vector field $X$ on $E$ is $G$-invariant if for every $p\in E$ and $g\in G$ we have $$dg_p(X(p))=X(g(p)).$$

Comment: @AmitaiYuval do you happen to have any idea on how to provide a  left-invariant vector field? because Tsemo's one is the only reasonable vector field I can think of

Comment: As I wrote earlier, it seems that Tsemo's answer is indeed the only choice-free vector field that can be associated with $u\in\mathfrak{g}$. In fact, this construction is a standard one. I'm only saying it is not $G$-invariant. To the best of my understanding, in order to obtain a $G$-invariant vector field associated to $u$, you would have to *choose* an identification of each fiber with $G$.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval and I totally agree with that. I'm confused because the statement clearly says "G-invariant"

Comment: Where did you find this statement? Could you add a precise citation to your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p:E\rightarrow M$ is a principal $G$-bundle, $E$ is endowed with an action of $G$ whose quotient space is $M$, let $u\in{\cal G}$, define $X_u(x) =  \left. \frac{d}{dt} \right|_{t=o} \exp(tu) \mathbin{.} x$.

Comment: What do you mean by $e^{tu}.x$? is it the usual multiplication which takes place in $\R^n$ for some $n$ once we observe that $E$ is a manifold?

Comment: In a Lie group, you have an exponential map $exp:{\cal G}\rightarrow G$, so if $u$ is an element of the Lie algebra, you can define $exp(tu)\in G$ and since $G$ acts on $E$, $exp(tu).x, x\in E$ makes sense.

Comment: @TsemoAristide I believe the vector field you are describing is *not* $G$-invariant.

Comment: ok but it seems that you are identifying the fibre with the Lie group, what happens if we change the identification? Is it well-defined? I'm sorry, I can't see it

Comment: The vector field described in this answer is very well-defined, but not $G$-invariant.

Comment: I am not identifying the fiber with the Lie group, you have an action $G\times E\rightarrow E$ defined by $(g,x)\rightarrow g.x\in E$, so since $exp(tu)\in G$, you can define $exp(tu).x$.

Comment: @TsemoAristide oh thanks!